# Polymorphic BelongsTo relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image]

How could I set relationships to use just one table (`model_types`) in Laravel to store types for cars and bikes?

**Car** model

```
public function carTypes() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(CarType::class);
}
```

**CarType** model (inverse relationship):

```
public function car()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
}
```

**Bike** model

```
public function bikeTypes() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(BikeType::class);
}
```

**BikeType** model (inverse relationship):

```
public function bike()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Bike::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options I can think of to solve this problem, the first being a simple table using a `type` column and the other is using polymorphic relations which is a little overkill.

---

The first option is to have a `type` column on your `model_types` table which you could use to determine the type and adding constants in your ModelType class like this:

```
const TYPE_CAR = 1;
const TYPE_BIKE = 2;
```

[image]

Then you can easily access the data like so, so from the Car model it's

```php
public function modelType() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ModelType::class)->where('type', ModelType::TYPE_CAR);
}
```

If you wanted to access it from the `model_types` table it would look like this:

```php
public function cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class)
}
```

```php
public function bikes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bike::class)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it reversed.
A car can belong to one car type, but one car type can apply to many cars.
The same goes for bikes.

You don't need a polymorphic relationship.

Car model

```
public function carType() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ModelType::class);
}
```

Bike model

```
public function bikeType() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ModelType::class);
}
```

ModelType model

```
public function cars()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
}

public function bikes()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Bike::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about inverse relationship, but in your Car model you should use

```
public function carTypes() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(ModelType::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Car Model:

```
public function carTypes() {
    return $this->hasMany(ModelType::class);
}
```

Bike Model:

```
public function bikeTypes() {
    return $this->hasMany(ModelType::class);
}
```

ModelType Model:

```
public function car() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'modeltype_car_id');
}

public function bike() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Bike::class, 'modeltype_bike_id');
}
```